# What is causing this java.lang.NullPointerException error?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am fairly new to Java, I've looked all over the Internet and stackoverflow itself to understand what I am doing wrong to no luck. Can someone please tell me why I get this error? I think I've initialized the array the right way and I think I've instantiated it right as well.

```
public class Grid {

 private Slot[][] array = new Slot[12][12];

 public Grid(){};


 public void printarray(){   

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++){
        System.out.print(i + "|" + "");
        for(int j = 1 ; j <= 10 ; j++){     

            System.out.print(array[i][j].getStatus());

        }//end inner for        

        System.out.print("\n");
    }//end outer for 
    System.out.print("\n");

};

}//end of class




public class Slot {


    public Slot(){};


    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    private int status = 0 ;
    private int id = 0 ;

}//end of slot

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Grid myGrid = new Grid();
    myGrid.printarray();
}//end of main
```

Comment: Which line throws the NPE? My guess is `System.out.print(array[i][j].getStatus());`. You made an array, but never put anything into it. `private Slot[][] array = new Slot[12][12];` doesn't automatically put Slots in there.

Comment: System.out.print(array[i][j].getStatus()); is what throws the NPE

Comment: You need something like `array[0][0] = new Slot();` for every element.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9043523/1864167) in particular.

Answer (score 3):

You've initialized the array properly, but it's still empty. You need to create objects of type `Slot` and populate the array before you can pull objects out and call methods on them.

```
System.out.print(array[i][j].getStatus());
```

That line is trying to pull a `Slot` from position i, j of your array, but there's nothing there, so it returns `null`. Calling `getStatus()` on a `null` reference is causing the exception.

Comment: You mean I would need to create 144 Slot Objects? I've done the same thing in c++ and the grid constructor calls the constructor for each slot so that there is no need to create them manually, does Java treat this cases differently?

Comment: If you want a 12x12 array of Slot objects, then yes you need to create 144 Slot objects.

Comment: @Lucawuz Yes, you need a loop or some other code to create those objects and add them to your array.  `new Slot[12][12]` in Java just creates the empty array for you.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. So new Slot[12][12] doesn't call the constructor of Slot?

Comment: @Lucawuz No, it only creates the array. It doesn't call the `Slot` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your array is initialized with nulls at every location.  You should initialize it with values in your constructor if you don't want the values to be null.  Also in your print statement you are not printing all the elements only the first 10 elements of the first 10 rows.

Since you declare it at the global level:

```
private Slot[][] array = new Slot[12][12];
```

every position `array[number][number]` will have null as its initial value. You could initialize in your constructor like:

```
public Grid(){
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++){
       for(int j = 0 ; j < 12 ; j++){
           array[i][j] = new Slot(0, 0);
       }
   }
}

public Slot(int id, int status){
     this.id = id;
     this.status = status;
}
```

Comment: For the printing part that's what I want it to do, I don't get why my elements are not initialized, shouldn't the grid constructor call the slot constructor 144 times on its own?

Comment: @Lucawuz No you will have to initialize each element of the array like above I posted an example constructor for the Grid class.

Comment: @Lucawuz I gave you an example of what your 2 constructors could look like.